# angularjs avoid empty field from the ngrepeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

The function seems to be fine when remove `| currency:"£"` filter. Is there any option to show only the current user amount ?

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('roomController', function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{
      id: 1,
      firstname: 'member',
      spent: 206.98
    }, {
      id: 2,
      firstname: 'member',
      spent: 12.23
    }, {
      id: 3,
      firstname: 'member',
      spent: 302.12
    }, {
      id: 4,
      firstname: 'member',
      spent: 198.21
    }, {
      id: 5,
      firstname: 'member',
      spent: 85.85
    }];
    $scope.currentuser = 4;
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="roomController">
    <h2 ng-repeat="user in users"><i class="fa fa-gbp"></i> {{ user.id === currentuser ? user.spent: '' | currency:"£"}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's possible to do it in expression:
`{{ user.id === currentuser ? (user.spent | currency:"£") : ''}}`, but I'd rather use `ng-if` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't need the ternary operator, instead put an `ng-if` in the `<h2>` that's being repeated.

See below:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('roomController', function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{
      id: 1,
      firstname: 'member',
      spent: 206.98
    }, {
      id: 2,
      firstname: 'member',
      spent: 12.23
    }, {
      id: 3,
      firstname: 'member',
      spent: 302.12
    }, {
      id: 4,
      firstname: 'member',
      spent: 198.21
    }, {
      id: 5,
      firstname: 'member',
      spent: 85.85
    }];
    $scope.currentuser = 4;
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="roomController">
    <h2 ng-repeat="user in users" ng-if="user.id === currentuser"><i class="fa fa-gbp"></i> {{ user.spent | currency:"£"}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```